# theming jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using datatable and dialog on same page, i would like to apply different themes for each. How do i achieve it? Currently my datatable theme is applied for both, how do i scope dialog.

Below is my dialog code

```
   $('#newVisit').dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: true,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                title: "Add New Visit"

//                    open: function () {
//                        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
//                    }


            });                    //.parent(".ui-dialog").wrap("<div class='theme-smoothness'></div>");
```

I have tried wrapping but didn't succeed.
any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying below code to implement them but could succeed, can anybody tell me what could be the proper solution
     $('#newVisit').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 'auto',
                    title: "Add New Visit"

                }).parent('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="redmond"></div>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using css specificity to define styles for the default jquery ui dialog styles?  try defining custom styles for these classes (based on dialog dynamic class insertion):

```
    <div class="**ui-dialog** ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
   <div class="**ui-dialog-titlebar** ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="**ui-dialog-title-dialog**" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" class="**ui-dialog-content** ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
      <p>Dialog content goes here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

you can see default layout/style reference here:

[click on "theming"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: I guess this is the markup generated by dialog, do i need to play with it?. i am looking for simple solution where i just need to scope jquery dialog.

Comment: yes, this is the markup created by dialog.js. as far as scoping, it's pretty simple.  when i scope ui widgets, i style .ui-dialog > ui-dialog-titlebar > .ui-dialog-content.  within .ui-dialog, i might place a div wrapper with an #id so i can do .ui-dialog div#id X X X so the styles i create win out in css specificity.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, i am using below code for wrapping but not able to change the style.
 $('#newVisit').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, draggable: true, width: 'auto', height: 'auto', title: "Add New Visit" }).parent('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="redmond"></div>');
What could be the reason??

Comment: ok, just be sure you see .redmond wrapped around .dialog in firebug.  what does your css look like? i used your code in jsfiddle to create simple style changes for a dialog using simple css.  see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/WwE4g/    this works because my css is small and not complicated. if you have a lot of css rules on your site, be sure your .redmond rules win out.

Comment: Thanks much for your suggestions, it really helps. its working